# How can I avoid Forms overlapping in codenameone?

Tags: java, codenameone

I have two Forms, Register and LogIn. After registering, user is redirected to the LogIn form, but once I call the logIn form (showForm("LogIn", null)), this form overlaps the Register Form - see screenshot.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/8t05lzodxcg88ur/form%20overlapping.PNG?dl=0

How can I avoid this Form overlapping?

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue also. I was using a custom UIID style and had to explicitly set the Color->Trasparency to 255.

If you are using a dialog, try setting the 'tintColor' in the Theme -> Constants. This can be used to have the previous form appear to 'grey-out' (depending in which tintColor you use) so the dialog doesn't appear to be overlapping.

Comment: I am using the existing Form UIID style. How did you set the color transparency to 255?

Comment: check out this video for more information on themes: http://www.codenameone.com/themeing.html

Comment: I've been playing around with color background and I pretty much changed all components to be 255. I changed containers, tabs, and forms, but it's still overlaps. I think the issue is that I am using the already-created LoginDialog GUI  - and the dialog is position in the center, north and south areas are not cover by the dialog and it's where overlapping is occurring.

Comment: oh, this is a dialog. try setting the 'tintColor' in the Theme -> Constants.

Comment: I think you got it, its just a dialog and somehow submitter changed the dialog styling so it doesn't really standout that this is a dialog and not a form...

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the form background to be transparent? Forms must be opaque in order for transitions to work properly.

Comment: I didn't changed the background. How can I verify/change the form background?

Comment: I've been setting backgrounds to be opaque to all major components - forms, tabs and containers and none worked. I think the issue is the already-created LoginDialog GUI that I've been using. The Dialog is position in the center, north and south areas are blank and it's where overlapping is occurring. I just fixed it by setting the tab (overlapping component) to be visible=false when log out button is fired.